# After migrating our website to a new server we are getting an error when trying to access Cartthrob

Tags: cartthrob, php-errors

After migrating our website to a new server we are getting an error when trying to access Cartthrob.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in /home/smctorg/public_html/dev.rdrneducation.com/system/expressionengine/third_party/cartthrob/mcp.cartthrob.php on line 215

Comment: Could you tell us which version of Cartthrob and EE your have installed, and if you upgraded either while migrating.

Comment: I did not upgrade Cartthrob and i'm running version 2.0302 according to the config file. EE was upgrading from version 2.1.3 to 2.8.1 during installation. I was afraid to uninstall Cartthrob and reinstall for fear of losing any information.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgraded EE to 2.8.1, you will need to upgrade CartThrob to 2.6. 2.6 was the first version of CartThrob tested with EE 2.8 [See CartThrob changelog](http://cartthrob.com/docs/pages/change_log/index.html)

You shouldn't need to uninstall cartthrob for any reason, a straight upgrade will be fine, although your jumping quite a few versions so extensive testing will be required.

Comment: I backed up my Cartthrob files and overwrote them with carthrob 2.6. The original error is gone but when I click on run module updates nothing happens and it still says i'm running version 2.0302.

Comment: I made a backup of the carttrob database files just incase and uninstalled the module then reinstalled. It now shows the correct version and everything is working correctly.

Comment: If you don't have it enabled already, enable debugging by changing debug=0 to debug=1 in whichever file your using to access the backend, either admin.php in the docroot, or index.php in the system folder. If there are any errors they will then be printed to the screen. If you get no errors, try upgrading to EE 2.9. 2.8.1 is just a horribly buggy build, I had quite a few issues that wouldn't go away, 2.9 fixed this. The EE upgrade will also have the side effect of running the module upgrade process at the same time, so may put the upgrade through, long shot though.